# Capitalize only the first letter of sentences in python,using split function

Tags: python

**How can I capitalize the first letter of a input sentence in python?**
Output has to be: Enter sentence to be capitalized:+ input sentence

```
input_string =input("Enter sentence to be capitalized: ")
def capitalize_first(input_string):
    output=input_string.split('.')
    i=0
    while i<len(output)-1:
        result=output[i][0].upper()+output[i][1:]+"."
    print("Enter sentence to be capitalized:"+result)
```

Comment: `sentence[0].upper() + sentence[1:]`?

Comment: Is it just the first character, or if it is a sentence, every word, like how headings work?

Comment: it does not work for more than one sentence. The input sentence should be given by user

Comment: @Gokce See my updated answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

How about `input_string.title()`?

```
input_string =input("Enter sentence to be capitalized: ")
def capitalize_first(input_string):
    result = input_string.title()
    print("Enter sentence to be capitalized:"+result)
```

This built-in method only capitalises the first character and keeps other ones lower, just like how titles work.

As you can see, the extra capitals in `THIS IS AN AMAZING` are changed.

```
>>> input_string = "Hello World THIS IS AN AMAZING day!!!"
>>> input_string.title()
>>> 'Hello World This Is An Amazing Day!!!'
```

Comment: Maybe add that it lowercases the rest of the characters?

Comment: @Griffon26 it should be clear when they run it. I will though.

Comment: The semantics of title() differ from capitalize_first() on that one point, so that's why I think it's worth mentioning. And as long as he feeds it lower case examples, he won't find the difference.

Comment: I actually meant it *makes* the rest lower case. Even letters that were capitals before.

Comment: @Suraj Kothari there ce

Comment: @Suraj Kothari there are more than one sentence. That is why I want to use split

Comment: @SurajKothari it capitalizes the beginning of all words:

Comment: here is the original question:Write a program with a function that accepts a string as an argument and
returns a copy of the string with the first character of each sentence 
capitalized. The program should let the user enter a string and then pass
it to the function, printing out the modified string.

Comment: @SurajKothari the idea should be converting: hello.this is an amazing day. have a nice day.>>>  Hello. This is an amazing day.Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence="test Sentence"
print(sentence.title()) #makes the first letter of every word in sentence capital
print(sentence[0].upper()+sentence[1:] ) #retains case of other charecters
print(sentence.capitalize()) #makes all other charecters lowercase
```

Output:

Test Sentence

Test Sentence

Test sentence

Answer your specific question

```
def modify_string(str1):
    sentence_list=str1.split('.')
    modify_this=input("Enter sentence to be modified: ")
    for idx, item in enumerate(sentence_list):
            modify_this_copy=modify_this
            if item.lower().strip()==modify_this.lower().strip():
                sentence_list[idx]=modify_this_copy[0].upper()+modify_this_copy[1:]
    return '. '.join(sentence_list)
string1="hello. Nice to meet you. hello. Howdy."
print(modify_string(string1))
```

Output

Enter sentence to be modified: hello

Hello.  Nice to meet you. Hello.  Howdy.

Comment: How is this retaining the case of `S` in sentence

Comment: @SurajKothari The second one will as commented

Comment: @nandukk what if you use .title()? It saves the two lines.

Comment: The last one is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are many ways to do so, but title() is the easiest. You can use upper() inside a for loop which iterating the input string, or even capitalize(). If the goal is to capitalise only the first letter of every word. Then you can't use above methods since they capitalise the word in traditional way (first letter is capitalise and others in simple letters regardless what user entered). To avoid that and keep any capitalise letters inside a word as it is, just like user entered.
Then this might be a solution

```
inputString=input("Your statement enter value or whatever")
seperatedString=inputString.split()
for i in seperatedString:
    i[0].upper()
    print("Anything you want to say" + i)
```